# Google App Engine: Public IP Address Subnets for white listing

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

Does anyone know if there is a set of IP addresses/subnets that GAE uses to serve up content/issue requests?  I have an app that needs to fetch a url from another service.  That service will only work if the fetch is from a whitelisted IP address.  Hence the question.

Thanks!
Rhett

Answer (score 2):

For Google Postini services:
http://www.google.com/support/appsecurity/bin/answer.py?answer=141669

Also I compiled this addresses from years of pinging :-)  and various forums. Can't guarantee thou that the list is accurate, can't find any official Google info on it other than that Google Postini link.

```
64.68.82.1 - 64.68.82.80

64.208.33.33

64.209.181.52

64.209.181.53

209.185.108.134 - 209.185.108.165

209.185.253.167 - 209.185.253.188
```

It's hard to say which ones you need exactly as the app will connect to the closest google's data center, and there at least 6 ones in US alone that I know of. I'm sure there are plenty more.

Answer (score 2):

Outgoing requests such as URLFetch will always be made from addresses in the list that `_netblocks.google.com`'s TXT record resolves to. Incoming requests could go to any address that `ghs.google.com` resolves to anywhere in the world - but since the address resolution is location-dependent, there's no practical way to get a complete list.

Note that in either case, addresses will change over time, so you should not resolve them once and expect that list to remain accurate indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

OK, this seems to be the answer--if anyone wants to chime in with a confirmation, let me know.  From http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/d1e592a4a535378a/318ffadfb5d6c949?lnk=gst&q=ip+address#318ffadfb5d6c949

URLFetch should use these blocks:

$ dig _netblocks.google.com TXT

Comment: According to the answer it's only for Google Apps. They would access from that block. Not internal apps trying to access google. Unless I misunderstood your question, that's not what you were looking for, were you?